# Suggestions for blindfold exercises

Tags: calculation, blindfold-chess, visualization

I can now name the color of any square. Does anyone have suggestions for  some other visualization exercises I can do to improve my blindfold chess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to replay whole games from memory after watching an animation of the whole game a couple of times. I use my own web app for this purpose which immediately reports the first deviation form the game. I sometimes turn on the blindfold setting and make the moves on an empty interactive chessboard. It is possible to go through a whole game like this.

For example, try this link https://tinyurl.com/srwuzqd to replay Morphy's opera game blindfold playing White. The system can be configured blindfold or not, replay one side or both.

Comment: My answer was marked with the green icon indicating that the author has accepted it but the complete solution involves using my editor to create such exercises as the opera demo I cited. Go to https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzle/editor.php and use the PGN import tab to load a game and then the general tab to enforce the blindfold mode.

Answer (score 8):

A friend of mine (and a stronger player) suggested one exercise which has helped me in developing my visualization skills.

Take a game, any game and read the first two moves of both sides (ie total four plies), visualize the position now on board, then make these moves on board, see if your visualized position was right.

Read the next two moves and visualize the current position then make the moves on board and check if you got it right.

Go through the entire game in these steps of two moves.

once you are fairly comfortable,  try in steps of three moves, Gradually increase the number of moves.

I am doing this for about 8 months now and now I can visualize boards over ~10-12 moves.

Already I play blindfold chess in lichess.org, by making the site speak out opponents move and I entering move through the keyboard. (Even though I look at the board once in ~10 moves)